# Pivot/ Crosstab Query Help needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a query like below which gives following result.

---

### Query

```
select OrderID, AccessName, Address1, Postcode, GeneralInstructions, --CompanyName,
col, --col+'_'+cast(rn as varchar(10)) col, 
val
from 
(
   select o.OrderID, js.JobStatusID, p.Name, o.AccessName, o.Address1, o.Postcode,   oj.GeneralInstructions, s.CompanyName
  , row_number() over(partition by o.OrderID 
                      order by js.JobStatusID) rn
FROM 
NEPCCO.Orders o
inner join NEPCCO.Clients c on o.ClientID = c.ClientID
inner join NEPCCO.OrderJobs oj on o.OrderID = oj.OrderID
inner join NEPCCO.Suppliers s on oj.SupplierID = s.SupplierID
inner join NEPCCO.Products p on oj.ProductID = p.ProductID
inner join NEPCCO.OrderStatus os on o.OrderStatusID = os.OrderStatusID
inner join NEPCCO.JobStatus js on oj.JobStatusID = js.JobStatusID
where 
o.OrderID in (50211, 44621) and 
(p.ProductID in (35,36,37,38,38,40,41,42,43) or  p.ProductID in (33,34))
 ) d
 unpivot
 (
   val
   for col in (Name)
) un
```

---

### First Output

```
OrderID     AccessName      Address1                PostCode   Col Val    
44621   Mr Hayden   7 Broad Rush Green  LU7 2XA    Name  FPA - 28
44621   Mr Hayden   7 Broad Rush Green  LU7 2XA    Name  AW EPR
50211   Mrs Godwin  64 Riverview    MK43 7PN       Name  FPA - 28
```

---

### Another Query for same thing to get desired output

```
select *
from
(
   select OrderID, AccessName, Address1, Postcode, GeneralInstructions, --CompanyName,
    col, --col+'_'+cast(rn as varchar(10)) col, 
    val
  from 
  (
    select o.OrderID, js.JobStatusID, p.Name, o.AccessName, o.Address1, o.Postcode, oj.GeneralInstructions, s.CompanyName
     , row_number() over(partition by o.OrderID,js.JobStatusID 
                      order by o.OrderID) rn
   FROM 
   NEPCCO.Orders o
   inner join NEPCCO.Clients c on o.ClientID = c.ClientID
   inner join NEPCCO.OrderJobs oj on o.OrderID = oj.OrderID
   inner join NEPCCO.Suppliers s on oj.SupplierID = s.SupplierID
   inner join NEPCCO.Products p on oj.ProductID = p.ProductID
   inner join NEPCCO.OrderStatus os on o.OrderStatusID = os.OrderStatusID
   inner join NEPCCO.JobStatus js on oj.JobStatusID = js.JobStatusID
   where 
   o.OrderID in (50211, 44621) and 
   (p.ProductID in (35,36,37,38,38,40,41,42,43) or  p.ProductID in (33,34))
    ) d
   unpivot
  (
   val
   for col in (Name)
  ) un
  ) s
 pivot
 (
 max(val)
 for col in (Name,JobStatusID,  JobStatusID1, Name1)
) piv
```

---

### Second Output which is near to desired one but not what I want

```
OrderID     AccessName      Address1            PostCode   Col              Val 
 44621  Mr Hayden   7 Broad Rush Green  LU7 2XA  FPA - 28   NULL     
 50211  Mrs Godwin  64 Riverview        MK43 7PN     FPA - 28   NULL
```

---

### Desired Output - Check the Column header names, which I want to show, from first query

```
OrderID     AccessName      Address1           PostCode   InstallJobType  EPR Type   
 44621  Mr Hayden   7 Broad Rush Green LU7 2XA    FPA - 28        AW EPR
 50211  Mrs Godwin  64 Riverview    MK43 7PN      FPA - 28        NULL
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am stuck

---

### DATA PRIOR TO UNPIVOT

```
OrderID     JobstatusId   Name      AccessName        Address1             PostCode    CompanyName         M

   44621    3         AW EPR    Mr Hayden   7 Broad Rush Green  LU7 2XA   N/A (Sole trader)                 1
   44621    14        FPA - 28  Mr Hayden   7 Broad Rush Green  LU7 2XA Just Energy Solutions Limited       2
   50211    17        FPA - 28  Mrs Godwin  64 Riverview        MK43 7PN    Just Energy Solutions Limited   1
```

---

EDIT - kindly check if I am doing it right as it gives my the desired output

```
select OrderID, AccessName, Address1, Postcode, GeneralInstructions, 
Name_1 as "Install Jobs", 
Name_2 as "EPR Jobs",
CompanyName,Name
from
(
  select OrderID, AccessName, Address1, Postcode, GeneralInstructions, CompanyName,
    col+'_'+cast(rn as varchar(10)) col, 
    val
  from 
  (
    select o.OrderID, js.JobStatusID, p.Name, o.AccessName, o.Address1, o.Postcode, oj.GeneralInstructions, s.CompanyName, 
    js.Name as "Install Job Status", js.JobStatusID as JS1
      , row_number() over(partition by o.OrderID 
                          order by o.OrderID) rn
    FROM 
    NEPCCO.Orders o
    inner join NEPCCO.Clients c on o.ClientID = c.ClientID
    inner join NEPCCO.OrderJobs oj on o.OrderID = oj.OrderID
    inner join NEPCCO.Suppliers s on oj.SupplierID = s.SupplierID
    inner join NEPCCO.Products p on oj.ProductID = p.ProductID
    inner join NEPCCO.OrderStatus os on o.OrderStatusID = os.OrderStatusID
    inner join NEPCCO.JobStatus js on oj.JobStatusID = js.JobStatusID
    where 
    o.OrderID in (50211, 44621) and 
    (p.ProductID in (35,36,37,38,38,40,41,42,43) or  p.ProductID in (33,34))
  ) d
  unpivot
  (
    val
    for col in (Name)
  ) un
) s
pivot
(
  max(val)
  for col in (JobStatusID_1, Name_1,  JobStatusID_2, Name_2,Name)
) piv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current query is confusing because you are applying UNPIVOT to only the `Name` column.  UNPIVOT is used to transform multiple columns into multiple rows. Based on the columns that you have in the PIVOT portion of your query, I am guessing that you need to UNPIVOT the `name` and the `JobStatus` columns.

If that is correct, then your query should be similar to the following:

```
select *
from
(
   select OrderID, AccessName, Address1, Postcode, 
    GeneralInstructions, --CompanyName,
    col+cast(rn as varchar(10)) col,
    val
  from 
  (
    select o.OrderID, 
      cast(js.JobStatusID as varchar(50)) JobStatusId, 
      cast(p.Name as varchar(50)) Name, 
      o.AccessName, o.Address1, o.Postcode, 
      oj.GeneralInstructions, s.CompanyName
     , row_number() over(partition by o.OrderID,js.JobStatusID 
                      order by o.OrderID) rn
     FROM NEPCCO.Orders o
     inner join NEPCCO.Clients c on o.ClientID = c.ClientID
     inner join NEPCCO.OrderJobs oj on o.OrderID = oj.OrderID
     inner join NEPCCO.Suppliers s on oj.SupplierID = s.SupplierID
     inner join NEPCCO.Products p on oj.ProductID = p.ProductID
     inner join NEPCCO.OrderStatus os on o.OrderStatusID = os.OrderStatusID
     inner join NEPCCO.JobStatus js on oj.JobStatusID = js.JobStatusID
     where o.OrderID in (50211, 44621) and 
       (p.ProductID in (35,36,37,38,38,40,41,42,43) or  p.ProductID in (33,34))
  ) d
  unpivot
  (
    val
    for col in (Name, JobStatus)
  ) un
) s
pivot
(
  max(val)
  for col in (Name, JobStatusID,  JobStatusID1, Name1)
) piv;
```

Edit, if you are going to have an unknown number of values, then you will need to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(col+cast(seq as varchar(10))) 
                    from
                    (
                       select   row_number() over(partition by o.OrderID,js.JobStatusID 
                          order by o.OrderID) seq
                       FROM NEPCCO.Orders o
                       inner join NEPCCO.Clients c on o.ClientID = c.ClientID
                       inner join NEPCCO.OrderJobs oj on o.OrderID = oj.OrderID
                       inner join NEPCCO.Suppliers s on oj.SupplierID = s.SupplierID
                       inner join NEPCCO.Products p on oj.ProductID = p.ProductID
                       inner join NEPCCO.OrderStatus os on o.OrderStatusID = os.OrderStatusID
                       inner join NEPCCO.JobStatus js on oj.JobStatusID = js.JobStatusID
                    ) d
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select 'Name', 1 union all
                      select 'JobStatusId', 2
                    ) c (col, so)
                    group by seq, col, so
                    order by seq, so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT *
            from 
            (
               select OrderID, AccessName, Address1, Postcode, 
                GeneralInstructions, --CompanyName,
                col+cast(rn as varchar(10)) col,
                val
              from 
              (
                select o.OrderID, 
                  cast(js.JobStatusID as varchar(50)) JobStatusId, 
                  cast(p.Name as varchar(50)) Name, 
                  o.AccessName, o.Address1, o.Postcode, 
                  oj.GeneralInstructions, s.CompanyName
                 , row_number() over(partition by o.OrderID,js.JobStatusID 
                                  order by o.OrderID) rn
                 FROM NEPCCO.Orders o
                 inner join NEPCCO.Clients c on o.ClientID = c.ClientID
                 inner join NEPCCO.OrderJobs oj on o.OrderID = oj.OrderID
                 inner join NEPCCO.Suppliers s on oj.SupplierID = s.SupplierID
                 inner join NEPCCO.Products p on oj.ProductID = p.ProductID
                 inner join NEPCCO.OrderStatus os on o.OrderStatusID = os.OrderStatusID
                 inner join NEPCCO.JobStatus js on oj.JobStatusID = js.JobStatusID
                 where o.OrderID in (50211, 44621) and 
                   (p.ProductID in (35,36,37,38,38,40,41,42,43) or  p.ProductID in (33,34))
              ) d
              unpivot
              (
                val
                for col in (Name, JobStatus)
              ) un
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(val)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Comment: I have edited the main post for unpivoted result. 

@Bluefeet - You are the king of Pivot queries man, all what I have achieved which I shown, is after reading your posts only. I have got high hopes from you. Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you open a session in Fiddle and I will share the queries?

Comment: @DotNetGeek All you have to do is create one yourself -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3

Comment: The inner query (with inner joins) is what I want partition the values to eliminate the duplicate rows. When I run the query which you shown, i get the error as 

Msg 8167, Level 16, State 1, Line 29
The type of column "JobStatusID" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

Comment: any idea ? I am badly stuck.

Comment: @DotNetGeek The columns that are being unpivoted must be the same datatype so you will have to cast the `jobstatusId` to be the same datatype as `name`. See my edit

Comment: Ok, thats close, but the third row with value "AW EPR" should be displayed along with as Name2, which is missing. Any idea on that. I am trying to paste/create the actual the actual tables in fiddle but its taking endless to create, so couldn't show you that.

Comment: Also, can we change the column names to be more understandable. like Name1 should display as "Install Jobs"

Comment: @DotNetGeek: You can always replace the `*` in the SELECT clause with `somename AS anothername, someothername AS yetanothername, ...`. Also, are your requirements changing or simply incomplete?

Comment: no, its not changing as I am nearly getting there, as the output is now, what I wanted. Just a cleanup needed to finish work.

Comment: @DotNetGeek If you need `Name2`, etc then you need to either add those columns to your PIVOT or if the number of values will be unknown you will have to use dynamic SQL to get the result. See my edit

Comment: check my edit @bluefeet and let me know. A big thanks. Your dynamic query didn't helped me as its missing the desired results/column values.

Comment: @DotNetGeek Don't edit my answer, edit your original question.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to it, did it by mistake.

Comment: @bluefeet: Mate, I did it and all credit goes to you. I knew you are the champ on Pivot queries and you proved it again. Thanks again.

Comment: @bluefeet: Sorry to bother you again, but I have one more query, going ahead to refine the resultset where I am missing few info. Could you help me on that?

Comment: @DotNetGeek If you have another question, then you should post a new question to the site.

Comment: @bluefeet: please see this link, I have posted the new question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366351/pivot-query-missing-records