# Pivot Query - Missing records

Tags: sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I have a pivot query which works well until now, but there has been a requirement where I need to specify a condition in the unpivot query which would omit the rows and column values which are not matching with the condition and displays me null. However, I need to show those value as a part of final results.

I have tried to do union to include the missing values, but won't get the desired output. I am pasting my pivot query below along with the results which are displayed and which needs to be displayed as a result. Please help.

### CURRENT QUERY

```
SELECT 
    OrderID, AccessName, Address1, Postcode
    , Gen_Instr_1 AS "General Instructions for Install"
    ,Supplier_Name_1 AS "Supplier Name"
    ,Install_Job_Name_1 AS "Install Jobs"
    ,Install_Job_Status_1 AS "Install Job Status"

    ,Install_Job_Name_2 AS "EPR Jobs"
    ,Install_Job_Status_2 AS "EPR Job Status"
FROM
(
    SELECT
    OrderID, AccessName, Address1, Postcode
    , col+'_'+CAST(rn AS VARCHAR(10)) col, 
    val
    FROM
    (
        SELECT o.OrderID, 
            CAST(js.JobStatusID AS VARCHAR(50)) JobStatusId
            , CAST(p.Name AS VARCHAR(50)) Install_Job_Name 
            , o.AccessName, o.Address1, o.Postcode
            , CAST(oj.GeneralInstructions AS VARCHAR(50)) Gen_Instr  
            , CAST(s.CompanyName AS VARCHAR(50)) Supplier_Name 
            , oj.SupplierID 
            , CAST(js.Name AS VARCHAR(50)) Install_Job_Status  
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY o.OrderID ORDER BY o.OrderID) rn
        FROM 
            NEPCCO.Orders o
            INNER JOIN NEPCCO.Clients c ON o.ClientID = c.ClientID
            INNER JOIN NEPCCO.OrderJobs oj ON o.OrderID = oj.OrderID
            INNER JOIN NEPCCO.Suppliers s ON oj.SupplierID = s.SupplierID
            INNER JOIN NEPCCO.Products p ON oj.ProductID = p.ProductID
            INNER JOIN NEPCCO.OrderStatus os ON o.OrderStatusID = os.OrderStatusID
            INNER JOIN NEPCCO.JobStatus js ON oj.JobStatusID = js.JobStatusID
        WHERE
            o.OrderID IN (6981,6860,6982,6983) AND
            (p.ProductID IN (35,36,37,38,38,40,41,42,43) OR  p.ProductID IN (33,34))
            AND s.CompanyName = 'Northern Gas Heating Ltd'
    ) d
    UNPIVOT
    (
        val
        FOR col IN (JobStatusId, Gen_Instr, Supplier_Name,Install_Job_Name, Install_Job_Status)
    ) un
) s
PIVOT
(
    MAX(val)
    FOR col IN (JobStatusID_1, Gen_Instr_1, Supplier_Name_1, Install_Job_Name_1, Install_Job_Status_1,
                JobStatusID_2, Gen_Instr_2, 
                Install_Job_Name_2, Install_Job_Status_2
                )
) piv
```

### CURRENT RESULTS - SEE THE NULL VALUES IN LAST TWO COLUMNS

```
OrderID AccessName Address1 Postcode SupplierName Install Jobs Install Job Status EPR Jobs EPR Job Status
    6981    Mrs Cespedes    73 Mill Lane    WV11 1DQ    Northern Gas Heating Ltd    GC1 - 28    Complete    NULL    NULL
    6983    Ms A Mirza  122 Pendleford Avenue   WV6 9EN     Northern Gas Heating Ltd    GC1 - 28    Complete    NULL    NULL
```

Now, if I runn the inner unpivot query as below, I get following records/rows

### Inner unpivot query

```
SELECT o.OrderID, 
            CAST(js.JobStatusID AS VARCHAR(50)) JobStatusId
            , CAST(p.Name AS VARCHAR(50)) Install_Job_Name
            , o.AccessName, o.Address1, o.Postcode
            , CAST(oj.GeneralInstructions AS VARCHAR(50)) Gen_Instr
            , CAST(s.CompanyName AS VARCHAR(50)) Supplier_Name
            , oj.SupplierID 
            , CAST(js.Name AS VARCHAR(50)) Install_Job_Status  
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY o.OrderID ORDER BY o.OrderID) rn1
        FROM 
            NEPCCO.Orders o
            INNER JOIN NEPCCO.Clients c ON o.ClientID = c.ClientID
            INNER JOIN NEPCCO.OrderJobs oj ON o.OrderID = oj.OrderID
            INNER JOIN NEPCCO.Suppliers s ON oj.SupplierID = s.SupplierID
            INNER JOIN NEPCCO.Products p ON oj.ProductID = p.ProductID
            INNER JOIN NEPCCO.OrderStatus os ON o.OrderStatusID = os.OrderStatusID
            INNER JOIN NEPCCO.JobStatus js ON oj.JobStatusID = js.JobStatusID
        WHERE
            o.OrderID IN (6981,6860,6982,6983) AND
            (p.ProductID IN (35,36,37,38,38,40,41,42,43) OR  p.ProductID IN (33,34))
```

that produces following results

```
 OrderID AccessName Address1 Postcode SupplierName Install Jobs Install Job Status EPR Jobs EPR Job Status

6860    6   AW EPR  01625555555 1 Gorsey Road   SK9 5DU     OGP 14  Cancelled     1
6981    4   AW EPR  Mrs Cespedes    73 Mill Lane    WV11 1DQ    Ian Barnhurst   1   Complete       1
6981    4   GC1 - 28    Mrs Cespedes    73 Mill Lane    WV11 1DQ    Northern Gas Heating Ltd    403 Complete      2
6982    4   AW EPR Installer    Mr N Singh  115 Oxbarn Avenue   WV3 7HQ     Northern Gas    414 Complete      1
6983    4   AW EPR Installer    Ms A Mirza  122 Pendleford Avenue   WV6 9EN Northern Gas    414 Complete      1
6983    4   GC1 - 28    Ms A Mirza  122 Pendleford Avenue   WV6 9EN     Northern Gas Heating Ltd    403 Complete     2
```

### Problem

Now, if you see carefully the above result set, which has the order id's `6860, 6982`, which is not included as a part of above result because it hasn't got the supplier name as `Northern Gas Heating Ltd`, moreover, the results which are displayed on first query, omits the values from order id's `6981, 6983`, also, because they have different suppliers.

Also, if you notice, with the records being displayed in first query, the values with row number 2 are not included.

I tried my best but failed. @bluefeet, your expertise highly required over here. Any clarifications please ask.

Comment: It would be very helpful to create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with your tables and some sample data.

Comment: I tried before, I copied the schema from my sql server and pasted in fiddle but it keep on building the schema and never generated one, moreover, i have got around 7 tables.

Comment: @bluefeet: its not allowing me to add more than 8000 characters :) any other alternative ?

Comment: Cut it down to the bare minimum for your problem.  Include only the columns needed for the question.

Comment: @bluefeet, I tried to do it, but its so time consuming and I have been given so much of work, I don't have much time and its very important task to finish. I would appreciate if you could show me some path and give me idea as what could be done, and I will try to make it work.